# PHP while loop to output multiple single PDFs using TCPDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, tcpdf

I would like to create multiple single page pdf's using the TCPDF library in a php while loop that pulls the information from a MySQL table.  My code is posted below.  It works correctly for one record and outputs one pdf, but ends the while loop before it should and the other pdf's never output.  I appreciate any insight.  Thank you in advance.

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('connection.php');


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_names";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $name = $row['name'];

        // create new PDF document
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);

        // add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();

        $html = '<div style="text-align:center"><h1>Title' .$name. '</h1></div>';

        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');


        // output the HTML content
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

        // reset pointer to the last page
        $pdf->lastPage();


        $pdf->Output("$name.pdf", 'D');
    }
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TCPDF can creates multiple PDF at the same time.
Suggest use PHP create loop instead or create multiple pages in single PDF.

Because $pdf->Output should be placed outside of the loop.
Otherwise, it will create single page then download only